# Neural Networks for predicting Energy at particular date

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, forecasting, backpropagation

I am trying to predict Solar Energy value at a particular date.For this purpose I am using the Artificial Neural Networks model.I am having problem in deciding the correct activation function. Since sigmoid function gives me output 0-1, I want to have and output like 256.33. So I thought to apply sigmoid for hidden layer and ReLu for output layer to keep non-linearity in networks.Can you suggest me what is the way to do this? Is my approach correct?

About my Architecture-I am using 3 layers, from which one is hidden-layer.(1) I tried to apply sigmoid for both the layers as activation function.(2)Then I applied ReLU activation for both the function. These two methods were failure. Now I am trying to apply ReLU on output layer and Sigmoid for hidden layer.

Comment: Why do you need a neural network?  Isn't physics enough?  Or are you taking measured input and trying to create a model from it?  Even in that case I would prefer classical regression to a NN.  I'm not sure I understand what you're doing.

Comment: Actually I want to create a model using weather data as inputs and Energy value as an output. So that I can use it for Solar Energy predictions. I have applied regression models it worked well but I have read few papers it says Neural Networks work better.@duffymo

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to choose some value for the maximum possible solar energy that can be generated in one day. Such as the maximum solar energy ever generated in one day or maximum solar energy possible in the best case scenario. Then use that value to scale the output of the Sigmoid function.

*f*(x) = *Sigmoid*(x) * MAX_ENERGY